Sharepoint JSON if else conditional on txtContent
I am trying to display different text in a multiline text field depending on the value in a separate single line text field. I can get the if statement to work with one condition but if I try to nest if conditions then the column outputs the JSON.
Here's my code:
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "=if([$PersonaTitle] == 'Developer', 'dev-test', 'test'), if([$PersonaTitle] == 'Manager','Manager test','not test'))"
}

One condition:

Nested conditions


The following should work
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "=if([$PersonaTitle] == 'Developer', 'dev-test', if([$PersonaTitle] == 'Manager','Manager test','not test'))"
}




I see, I was adding an optional text for each condition but there can only be one.
